# issues with regex for .htaccess rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have something like this in .htaccess for my website:

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ profilescorta.php?t=$1 [L]

So if a user is accessing a link like: http:// url/1231231234 - the page is displayed correctly

Now, if someone tries to access a link like: http:// url/123.123.1234 - the 404 error page is showed.

I have added this rule to .htaccess
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+).(.*) $1$2 [N]

If someone is accesing: http:// url/123.123.1234 - the page is correctly displayed but now the problem is that the same page has 2 different links:
http:// url/123.123.1234 and http:// url/1231231234

Is there anyway I can make that when someone is accessing http://url/123.123.1234 to be redirected to http://url/1231231234?

Thanks,
Bogdan

Comment: Redirecting means you need to send http 301 header?
What is the exact data your are trying match ?
Is it something like an IP address ?

Comment: I have modified a little your answer and I think I made it work. So I changed your rule with:

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\.(.*) /$1$2 [R]

Answer (score 0):

New solution:

```
#Better 1 redirect /123.123.1234 -> /1231231234
#Assume phone number in this format: [3 Digits] Dot [3 Digits] Dot [4 Digits]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{4})$ /$1$2$3 [R=301]
```

Old bad solution:

```
[Bad] Double redirect /123.123.1234 -> /123123.1234 -> /1231231234
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+).(.*) /$1$2 [R]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatelly if I put the rule you have mentioned, everything gets messed up.

So the ideea is like this, the php query is about a phone number which is 10 digits long like 1231231234. 
Now if someone types http:// url/123.123.1234 (this format for the phone number) the 404 eror page is displayed since the query I make is not for 123.123.1234 but for 1231231234.

I want to redirect, if someone types 123.123.1234 in the url to 1231231234.
Example: http://escortele.eu/0725073448, http://escortele.eu/0725.073.448

Comment: I added better solution after getting the URL rules from you. This one is more restrictive and do one redirect, the old one did double redirect.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will check and reply whether is working or now. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: RewriteRule ^([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{4})$ /$1$2$3 [R=301] - this is not working in my case... Not sure how to explain you to understand..

The query from the php script is made by the phone number which is in format: 1231231234. So it's like profilescorta.php?t=1231231234.

The rule: RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ profilescorta.php?t=$1 [L] just rewrites the url from http: //url/profilescorta.php?t=$1 to http: //url/1231231234 (where 1231231234 is the argument for t=$1, so $1 would be 1231231234).

Sorry cannot explain so good, no. of chars here are quite limited and my reputation is only 1